# How to combine two rows in R?

Tags: r

I would like to combine/sum two rows based on rownames to make one row in R. The best route might be to create a new row and sum the two rows together.

Example df:

```
A  1  3  4  6  
B  3  2  7  9
C  6  8  1  2 
D  3  2  8  9
```

Where A,B,C,D are rownames, I want to combine/sum two rows (A & C) into one to get:

```
A+C  7  11  5  8  
B    3  2   7  9
D    3  2   8  9
```

Thank you.

Comment: Generally these type of operation are easier to perform on columns than rows so you might want to consider transposing your data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace the `A` row using the standard addition arithmetic operator, and then remove the `C` row with a logical statement.

```
df["A", ] <- df["A", ] + df["C", ]
df[rownames(df) != "C", ]
#   V2 V3 V4 V5
# A  7 11  5  8
# B  3  2  7  9
# D  3  2  8  9
```

For more than two rows, you can use `colSums()` for the addition.  This presumes the first value in `nm` is the one we are replacing/keeping.

```
nm <- c("A", "C")
df[nm[1], ] <- colSums(df[nm, ])
df[!rownames(df) %in% nm[-1], ]
```

I'll leave it up to you to change the row names. :)

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(V2 = c(1L, 3L, 6L, 3L), V3 = c(3L, 2L, 8L, 2L), 
    V4 = c(4L, 7L, 1L, 8L), V5 = c(6L, 9L, 2L, 9L)), .Names = c("V2", 
"V3", "V4", "V5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D"))
```

Answer (score 9):

`aggregate` to the rescue:

```
aggregate(df, list(Group=replace(rownames(df),rownames(df) %in% c("A","C"), "A&C")), sum)
#  Group V2 V3 V4 V5
#1   A&C  7 11  5  8
#2     B  3  2  7  9
#3     D  3  2  8  9
```

Answer (score 0):

matrix multiply?

```
> A <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1), 3)
> A                                        
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    1
> A %*% X
     V2 V3 V4 V5
[1,]  7 11  5  8
[2,]  3  2  7  9
[3,]  3  2  8  9
```

Or using the `Matrix` package for sparse matrices:

```
fac2sparse(factor(c(1,2,1,4))) %*% X
```