# Dplyr merge rows based on one column value and sum other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

My current df looks like the following:

```
 WEEK     COUNT    COUNT2    PERCENTAGE
2017-53    10        15         .05
2018-00    5         10         .1
2018-01    7         9          .1
....
2018-52    10        12         .06
2019-00    6         10         .05
....
```

What I would like to do is combine the last two weeks of each year together into the  final week of the year and combine `COUNT, COUNT2, and PERCENTAGE`. The weeks I currently have that I would like to combine are: `2017-53 and 2018-00`, `2018-52 and 2019-00`, `2019-52 and 2020-00`. Which I would like to merge into `2017-53, 2018-52, 2019-52` My expected output would be the following:

```
 WEEK     COUNT    COUNT2    PERCENTAGE
2017-53    15        25         .15
2018-01    7         9          .1
....
2018-52    16        22         .11
....
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`, after converting the 'WEEK' to `Date` class, `arrange` by that column, extract the 'year', create a grouping with 'WEEK' based on the difference of adjacent elements of 'year', and then `summarise` to get the `sum` of the columns that `matches` 'COUNT' or 'PERCENTAGE'

```
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr) #1.0.0
df1 %>% 
   mutate(Date = as.Date(str_c(WEEK, "-01"), format = '%Y-%U-%w')) %>% 
   arrange(Date) %>% 
   mutate(year = year(Date)) %>% 
   group_by(WEEK = case_when(lag(year, default = first(year)) - year < 0 ~ 
          lag(WEEK), TRUE ~ WEEK)) %>%
    summarise(across(matches("COUNT|PERCENTAGE"), sum))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  WEEK    COUNT COUNT2 PERCENTAGE
#  <chr>   <int>  <int>      <dbl>
#1 2017-53    15     25       0.15
#2 2018-01     7      9       0.1 
#3 2018-52    16     22       0.11
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(WEEK = c("2017-53", "2018-00", "2018-01", "2018-52", 
"2019-00"), COUNT = c(10L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 6L), COUNT2 = c(15L, 
10L, 9L, 12L, 10L), PERCENTAGE = c(0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.06, 0.05
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `colSums()` as is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755566/how-to-combine-two-rows-in-r), but it's a bit convoluted. I'd recommend using `aggregate` and pipes, as is shown further down in the same link.

Hope this helps!